# What is XAP file on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xap

I really want to know what the XAP file on Windows Phone 7 is; how important it is; and how I can create it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XAP is the application package - it is the distributable unit that allows you to install the application on a device (or emulator). Basically, it is a ZIP file with a different extension. If you change XAP to ZIP, you'll be able to read its contents fairly easy.

The XAP file format was inherited from standard Silverlight, and since WP7 is built around the same fundamental core, the file format remained unchanged.

Here is a pretty good description of what it does (remember, that even though it talks about Silverlight, the same main idea applies to WP7):
http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/dinesh/archive/2010/08/18/what-is-xap-file.aspx

Comment: Thaks Dennis. Could you tell me how I can create the xap file for windows phone 7, please?

Comment: It will get created when you run the application that all file that need to be deployed with your application

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio and have the Windows Phone 7 SDK installed, the XAP package will be created for you automatically when the project is built.

Comment: If you are already building a project, then take a look in the /bin/debug and /bin/release directories to find the XAP that the project is already building for you.

Comment: Also note that XAP files are created for games written in XNA, not just Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dennis' excellent post, one other thing about a XAP file - it's a ZIP file - so if you want to look inside one, then just rename it to .zip and then open it using a normal ZIP browser (e.g Windows explorer)