# Create WP7.1 Store package with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, app-store, windows-phone-7.1

I developed a WP7.1 App in Visual Studio 2012 and I'd like to create the Store/App Package.
The documentation says I should have a "Project" > "Store" > "Create App Package" menu option, but there is no "Store" option in my "Project" Tab.

Do I have to link my project with a store project first or something like that? Because I searched that option in the properties and Manifest files, but couldn't find it.

I'm sure I'm just completely oblivious right now, but this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build your application in `Release` mode and the package will be generated automatically into your projects' `\bin\Release\` directory.

It has `.xap` extension.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the Windows Store package creation mechanism. Even though the applications might share some code, the Windows Phone package creation is different.

When you build a Windows Phone application, you get a XAP file ([what is a XAP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190511/303696)). The XAP file is generated each time you build your solution. Depending on whether you are using the **Debug** or **Release** configurations, the package will be located in `PROJECT_FOLDER\bin\Debug` or `PROJECT_FOLDER\bin\Release`.

When submitting to the Windows Phone Marketplace, you should **ONLY** use the package that is built in **Release**.